# Reconciling Differences Between Python List Sort and ArcMap Table Sort

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, sorting

I have a feature class being used in Data Driven Pages, which sorts as follows:

- APPLE LARRY
- JOHNSON SHIRLEY
- KENT-STATE-GOODS LLC
- KENT TIMOTHY
- KENT VANESSA
- KENT WAYNE
- SMITH JEEVES

I also have the Data Driven Pages run via a script, and because we don't yet have ESRI Production Mapping, table generation has to be done as part of this script.  When this script runs, a Python list is created containing these names.  My list parcelOwners[] is then sorted using parcelOwners.sort(), but I get a different sort order amongst the KENT's because of the hyphen.  That sort order is as follows:

- APPLE LARRY
- JOHNSON SHIRLEY
- KENT TIMOTHY
- KENT VANESSA
- KENT WAYNE
- KENT-STATE-GOODS LLC
- SMITH JEEVES

As you could imagine, the difference in sort order causes problems when the tables generate for a given set of pages amongst the KENT names.  Page 3 gets the table data intended for Page 4, 4 for 5, 5 for 6, and 6 for 3.  Is there a way to change how Python sorts my list when it encounters hyphens to match how ArcMap sorts the same data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [sorted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) with a [lambda](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) function [replacing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) "-" with spaces:

```
names = ['APPLE LARRY','KENT TIMOTHY','KENT VANESSA','KENT WAYNE','KENT-STATE-GOODS LLC','SMITH JEEVES','JOHNSON SHIRLEY']
sorted(names, key=lambda x: x.replace("-", " "))
print names

>['APPLE LARRY', 'JOHNSON SHIRLEY', 'KENT-STATE-GOODS LLC', 'KENT TIMOTHY', 'KENT VANESSA', 'KENT WAYNE', 'SMITH JEEVES']
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much @BERA!  This is exactly what I was looking for.